# Ubuntu 20 won't boot anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, gnome, uefi, reboot

Bought a new SSD [along side my m.2 which has Win10 on it]. Installed the latest Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS as an Uefi system. Install went smooth, no issues. Rebooted twice [just in case].
Run apt `update & upgrade`, and a few minor tweaks. Then I installed `gnome-tweak-tool` and started downloading different themes, and fiddling around with the Tweaks. It said that I need to logout in order for the changes to take affect, so I did and after that I get a blank screen with a flat cursor blinking in the top left screen. Reboot and shut down do not help in any way.

If I did something wrong [can't see how though] i can just erase the sdd and start over [no real data has been lost].

But I'd rather try to save the installation in order to learn what went wrong if someone has an idea?

Comment: When you reboot does it get past uefi and or grub? You can fix a misconfigured home directory from something like a the Ubuntu Live CD Installer.

Comment: @Ohiovr Nope. When I restart after the motherboard logo i get the black screen with the blinking horizontal cursor. Win10 boot works fine.